# Prove that there is only one way to make a square using all seven tangram pieces

Tags: puzzle, geometry

I am pretty sure there is only one way to make a square from the seven tangram pieces:

[image: Tangram square]

How can I prove this is the only way respecting all symmetries?

Comment: I have no solution for this question but the answer might be related to the number of different lengths and angles. You know that the four corners of must be equal to 90°, four edges must have equal lengths.

Comment: @jlandercy's remark makes this a finite problem, so it can at least be tackled by a computer: One can show that all piece edges must lie on a few horizontal, vertical, diagonal grid lines; hence each piece can occupy only finitely many positions.

Comment: For large values of six....

Answer (score 2):

This is not a exactly a proof, mostly milestones towards a solution. This is a community wiki, feel free to edit.

First, you must consider than your tan-gram has 7 pieces (You may update your title):

- 2 Large Right Triangles (A);
- 1 Medium Right Triangle (B);
- 2 Small Right Triangles (C);
- 1 Square (D);
- 1 Parallelogram (E).

Second, if we assume the tan-gram to have an area of $a^2$ there are 4 different possible edge lengths: $a,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}a, \frac{1}{2}a, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}a$. Tan-gram square (horizontal and vertical directions) edges have a length equal to $a$. All horizontal and vertical subdivisions are ratio of this fundamental length. In the same way, Tan-gram diagonal length is equal to $\sqrt{2}$, all diagonal edges are ratio of this length.

Therefore parts with edge length that are rational product of $\sqrt{2}$  must be diagonals, and others are straight.

Third, it follows that parts A must form a bigger triangle in a corner of the tan-gram. Thus the problem resume to make an equivalent triangle with the 5 parts left (B,C,C,D,E).

Fourth, following the same logic, square D is internal part and then triangle B must be at the corner.

Fifth, triangles C must have their hypotenuses straight, so they have to share edges with square B.

Finally, there is only one place for parallelogram E.

I hope this helps!